# How to limit value assignment in foreach?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

Here is my `array` and `foreach`:

```
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

foreach ($colors as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

I need to just assign only the first three keys and I want this output:

```
red
green
blue
```

I can do that like this:

```
$i=1;
foreach ($colors as $value) {
    if ($i=4){break;}
    echo "$value <br>";
    $i++;
}
```

But I think using a `if()` statement in a loop (in reality my array has more than 100 elements) is not optimized, so there is any better approach for doing that ?

Comment: Is `array_slice()` and then `implode()` a solution for you? http://php.net/array_slice http://php.net/implode

Comment: change to a for loop i.e. for($i=0;$i<count(colors)-1;$i++){//do stuff}

Comment: @CharlotteDunois tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_slice()`.
Here is an example:

```
foreach (array_slice($colors,0,3) as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change your loop to a for loop and count to the length -1

```js
for($i=0;$i<count($colors)-1;$i++){
  //do stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For loop will take first 3 values only and it will print accordingly.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) //First 3 values will be considered.
{
$color=$colors[$i];
echo $color;
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the range function:

```
foreach(range(0,2) as $key) {
echo $colors[$key] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Worst solution of all the posted ones. Might work, but a `for` loop is better.